# Script is being loaded but not executed (Turbo links)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have this script:

```
   ready = ->
((d, s, id) ->
  js = undefined
  fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
  console.log("Loaded")
  return  if d.getElementById(id)
  js = d.createElement(s)
  js.id = id
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1"
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore js, fjs
) document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"
```

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load',ready)

it's for creating a facebook badge on a website. However, despite making a `ready` function and loading the function on `page:load`, the facebook badge only appears when a page is refreshed, classic behaviour expected of a turbolinks project that isn't configured properly. I don't really know what else to do.

The script is being loaded as an asset in chrome, but it must be loaded after everything else. I used [this online converter](http://js2coffee.org/) to convert an existing script, and it does work as coffee script, but only after a refresh.

**Update**

Here's the worrying thing. See that `console.log` on line 5? That logs successfully to the console first time on the load of a new page, so what's going on?

Comment: The problem is that `$(document).ready` is called only when the DOM finished loading.  Turbolinks uses AJAX (or something) to load new data into the DOM, without initiating an entire page request.  So the `$(document).ready` function doesn't fire when the page changes due to turbolinks.  I know there's better ways to handle this (that's why this is a comment, not an answer), but one quick hack is to add a line of JavaScript to the HTML that turbolinks is loading that will execute your `ready` function immediately:  `... <script type="text/javascript">if (window.jQuery) ready();</script>...`

Comment: But doesn't my `$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load',ready)` solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in Rails 5, try this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // your code goes in here
});
```